# Getting junk data in messages being sent with TcpClient and TcpListener

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I have several other pieces of network code running using identical code and I have never seen this before. The remaining bytes in the receiving buffer are getting filled with `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\`

I have seen this asked a few times, but there has never been an answer.

`TcpListener tlist = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip.ToString()), 27275);`

Once there is a connection. . .

```
byte[] byData = new byte[textBox.Text.Length];
byData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox.Text);
client.Send(byData, 0, byData.Length, 0);
```

And the receiving end:

```
byte[] bufferRec = new byte[56];
tc.Client.Receive(bufferRec, 0, 56, 0);
string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufferRec);
```

The buffer size I typically use is 256, and it is rare I am actually sending/receiving 256 bytes of data, but I never see those remaining bytes get filled with junk data, only in this case.

Edit: I can of course simply parse out the junk data, but it is still strange behaviour given there is no reason for it.

Comment: Note that `\0` is a *character*, not a byte. I suspect the bytes are just zeroes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value of [`Socket.Receive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5(v=vs.110).aspx) which tells you how many bytes have been read - which is just like ignoring the return value of `Stream.Read`. So your buffer contains more bytes than you've actually received, and your string therefore includes a lot of U+0000 characters. For example, taking a buffer of length 16 and the text "HELLO"

```
buffer: 48 45 4C 4C 4f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Return value: 5 (5 bytes received)
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffer): "HELLO\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffer, 0, 5): "HELLO"
```

Basically, you should only use the part of the buffer which contains data which has been received. You should also not assume that a single call to `Receive` (or `Stream.Read`) will read *all* the data in one go, even if your buffer is big enough to receive it. TCP is a streaming protocol, so all the normal caveats around streaming apply. If you're trying to write a message-oriented protocol, you'll need to layer that on top of TCP (e.g. by having a "header" part which indicates how much data is in the next message).

As an aside, it's rarely a good idea to use the underlying socket directly from `TcpClient` - the main point of using it is that you can use higher level abstractions such as `GetStream()`.

Comment: "Basically, you should only use the part of the buffer which contains data which has been received." Right but that's the issue, it's receiving a pile of garbage data, instead of nothing where there is no data being sent. The typical behaviour of the buffer isn't to fill up the rest with random 0's and slashes, it usually just puts nothing there.

Comment: @user1438893: You're ignoring the return value of `tc.Client.Receive`, so I don't know how you think you're telling the difference between the part of the buffer that corresponds to data that's been received and the part of the buffer that doesn't. Note that the character shown in the debugger as `\0` in a string is U+0000, which is usually the result of decoding a byte 0. Perhaps that was confusing you?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you would do with the return value of Receive when you're placing data into the buffer _inside_ the call to Receive. Are you supposed to discard the original buffer, check the size, make a new buffer, and copy the one with the junk data into the new one with the correct size? I am curious because I have never seen or heard of any of this behaviour being necessary.

Comment: @user1438893: No, you're supposed to use that data when calling `GetString`, e.g. `string output = Encoding.UTF8.Getstring(bufferRec, 0, bytesReceived)`. Although you should note that it could be problematic if part of a string is received in one call, and part in another - particularly if it's in the middle of a character not in the BMP. It would be better to use `tc.GetStream()` and wrap it in a `StreamReader` to handle that. I'm surprised you've never seen this, as it's *completely* standard for all stream-based operations.

Comment: Oh, I see, when getting the string. That makes sense then. As far as the `StreamReader` are you referring to sending an initial message containing what the next message size will be, then doing `stream.Read()` until all bytes are received?

Comment: @user1438893: No, if you do that then you don't need `StreamReader` and can just convert the whole `byte[]` into text in one go; this was about if your stream *only* contained text data, `StreamReader` would allow you to handle it without worrying about characters breaking across packets etc.

Comment: I'm usually sending a maximum of 10 bytes of data at any given time so I haven't seen any splitting yet, and that is only string data, but I will look into that as well. Thanks